# Can anyone tell me how to improve the run time of this code?

Tags: java, runtime

I have written a program to solve Diophantine equations in the form

> > A<sup>5</sup> + B<sup>5</sup> + C<sup>5</sup> + D<sup>5</sup> + E<sup>5</sup> = 0;

It should run in N<sup>3</sup>long(N) time, but it usually takes about 10 minutes for an input size of 100. Can anyone tell me whats wrong?

```
public class EquationSolver {

//Solves Equations of type: A^5 + B^5 + C^5 + D^5 + E^5 = F^5

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a max value: ");
    int N = input.nextInt();
    long START_TIME = System.nanoTime();
    SLinkedList test = new SLinkedList();
    SLinkedList test2 = new SLinkedList();
    test = setupLeftList(N);
    test2 = setupRightList(N);
    System.out.println("Note: This program takes about 7 minutes to complete for input of 100");
    test = mergeSort(test);
    test2 = mergeSort(test2);
    long END_TIME2 = System.nanoTime() - START_TIME;
    System.out.println("Total Time:" + END_TIME2/1000000000.0);
    checkEquality(test, test2);
    long END_TIME3 = System.nanoTime() - START_TIME;
    System.out.println("Total Time:" + END_TIME3/1000000000.0);

}


public static SLinkedList setupLeftList(long boundary)
{
    //Creates and returns an linkedList of all possible A,B,C values and their sums
    SLinkedList leftSums = new SLinkedList();
    for(long c = 0; c < boundary; c++)
    {
        for(long b = 0; b < c; b++)
        {
            for(long a = 0; a < b; a++)
            {
                    long sum = (long)(Math.pow(a+1,5)) + (long)(Math.pow(b+1, 5)) + (int)(Math.pow(c+1, 5));
                    Node current = new Node (sum, a+1, b+1, c+1, null);
                    //System.out.println(sum);
                    leftSums.addLast(current);
            }
        }
    }
    return leftSums;
}
public static SLinkedList setupRightList(long boundary)
{
    //Creates and returns an linkedList of all possible D,E,F values and their sums
    SLinkedList rightSums = new SLinkedList();
    for(int f = 0; f < boundary; f++)
    {
        for(int e = 0; e < f; e++)
        {
            for(int d = 0; d < e; d++)
            {   
                long sum = (long)(Math.pow(f+1, 5)) - ((long)(Math.pow(d+1, 5)) + (long)(Math.pow(e+1,5)));

                    Node current = new Node (sum, d+1, e+1, f+1, null);
                    //System.out.println(current.getSum());
                    rightSums.addLast(current); 

            }
        }
    }
    return rightSums;
}

public static SLinkedList mergeSort(SLinkedList sums)
// Sorts each list by the value of the sum
{

    if (sums.length() > 1 )
    {

    SLinkedList[] splitList = split(sums);
    SLinkedList s1 = mergeSort(splitList[0]);
    SLinkedList s2 = mergeSort(splitList[1]);
    sums = merge(s1, s2);

    }
    return sums;
}

public static SLinkedList[] split(SLinkedList sums)
{
    // Splits a linked list into two (somewhat) equal halves
    long midpoint = sums.length()/2;

    Node midPoint = sums.elementAt(midpoint); 

    SLinkedList s1 = new SLinkedList(sums.head, midPoint, midpoint);
    SLinkedList s2 = new SLinkedList(midPoint, sums.tail, midpoint);
    SLinkedList[] both = new SLinkedList[]{s1, s2};
    return both;
}

public static SLinkedList merge(SLinkedList s1, SLinkedList s2)
{
    // Merges two sorted lists of elements
    SLinkedList sMerged = new SLinkedList();
    while(!s1.isEmpty() && !s2.isEmpty())
    {
        if (s1.getFirst().getSum() < s2.getFirst().getSum())
        {
            sMerged.addLast(s1.removeFirst());
        }
        else
        {
            sMerged.addLast(s2.removeFirst());
        }
    }
    while(!s1.isEmpty())
    {
        sMerged.addLast(s1.removeFirst());
    }
    while(!s2.isEmpty())
    {
        sMerged.addLast(s2.removeFirst());
    }
    return sMerged;
}

public static void checkEquality(SLinkedList left, SLinkedList right)
{
    // Checks two linked lists for nodes that contain the same Sum value
    boolean ans = false;
    while (left.isEmpty() == false && right.isEmpty() == false)
    {
        long currentLeft = left.getFirst().getSum();
        long currentRight = right.getFirst().getSum();
        if (currentLeft > currentRight)
        {
            right.removeFirst();
        }
        else if(currentLeft < currentRight)
        {
            left.removeFirst();
        }
        else
        {
            if (left.getFirst().getC() <= right.getFirst().getA())
            {
                System.out.println("Answer Found: " + "A: " + left.getFirst().getA() + " B: " + left.getFirst().getB() + " C: " 
                    + left.getFirst().getC() + " D: " + right.getFirst().getA() + " E: " + right.getFirst().getB() + " F: " + right.getFirst().getC());
                ans = true;
            }

            Node temp = left.getFirst().getNext();

            while (temp.getSum() == currentRight)
            {
                if (temp.getC() <= right.getFirst().getA())
                {
                    System.out.println("Answer Found: " + "A: " + left.getFirst().getA() + " B: " + left.getFirst().getB() + " C: " 
                        + left.getFirst().getC() + " D: " + right.getFirst().getA() + " E: " + right.getFirst().getB() + " F: " + right.getFirst().getC());
                    ans = true;

                }
                temp = temp.getNext();

            }

            right.removeFirst();
            left.removeFirst();

        }
    }
    if (ans == false)
    {
        System.out.println("No answer found.");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You might want to benchmark your runtime for different input size to verify that your algorithm is indeed O N^3 log N.

Answer (score 2):

The definitive answer is: use a profiler and see what causes a bottleneck...

But I see you have [Math.pow()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Math.java#Math.pow%28double,double%29) calls, all with longs, and their 5th power.

You could do it quicker, while even detecting the overflow:

```
public static long pow5(long base) {
  if(base <=6208 && base >=-6208) {
    return base*base*base*base*base;
  } else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Overflow!");
  }
}
```

(**Magic number disclaimer:** 6208<sup>5</sup> is ~2<sup>63</sup>, is a number is bigger than that, the 5th power won't fit into 64 bits...)

Math.pow uses doubles, which means a lot of conversion in itself...

Also, **@Floris** pointed out that it is not even worth computing this over and over again - it could be put into a nice array, and just index that

```
public static long[] pow5 = getPow5(100);

public static long[] getPow5(long numElements) {
    long[] toReturn = new long[numElements];

    for(long i=0;long<numElements;long++) {
        toReturn[i] = i*i*i*i*i;
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

And where needed, instead of `Math.pow(x, 5)` just use `pow5[x]`

Comment: Thank you! Ill try this. Also, Ive timed each part, and merge sort is taking the longest which is backwards from what it should be...

Comment: The merge sort calls `split` which does all kinds of memory allocation with all the `new SlinkedList` calls. Probably quite an inefficient implementation. Also - I believe you only ever compute the 5th power of numbers between 0 and 100 - compute it once and look it up might be faster (depends on whether the lookup table stays in cache - it's less than 1kB in size...).

Comment: @Floris thanks, I didn't even delve deep into the implementation of the linkedlist - and the lookup idea is really a good one. I think on any reasonable CPU it should stay near the ALUs...

Comment: Does your `getPow5` code actually work? I'm a C guy, but I would have thought that `toReturn` is allocated on the stack, and not valid after the function returns. Better create the static at the main level, and pass the pointer in. Although I have been known to create the static array at the function level to get around this (don't tell the syntax police or they will hunt me down).

Comment: @Floris Yes, Java is quite a bit different from C - for one pointers as such don't exist, just object references. It would be possible to rewrite it so that the method would accept a `long[]` argument, which it would fill until its full using the `length`.

Comment: Thanks for educating me! So an object created in one function "survives" the function returning? When / how do things get cleaned up then? My whole universe just got a memory leak. It is clear that I need to actually sit down and learn Java rather than just hope I can "pick it up as I go along"

Comment: @Floris it's a pleasure, when there is a smart audience :) In Java, there is no destructor, as in C++, and no direct way of freeing up the memory, as `free()` in C. There is the Garbage Collector for this purpose. Very-very simplified: every object has its references counted, and when an object is not referenced anymore, at the next Garbage Collection, the memory associated with the object will be freed up. I programmed in C in my early days too, and I admit: At first it is a very odd thing, compared to malloc-free... You don't have control over freeing up the memory...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and the compliment :). One last question then: if you do `pow1 = pow5(10); pow2 = pow5(20)'`, two objects are created? But `pow1=pow5(5); ...; pow1=pow5(10);` would destroy the first copy when the second is created; but what if we had a `foo = pow1;` in between? In other words - does `foo = someArray;` make a copy, or a reference? To the object, or the variable?

Comment: @Floris you are on track! It works just that way. In the first case, two separate objects are created, with one reference to each. In the second case, one reference would at one time point to the first, and then to the second object, and the first would lose all the references, so the next GC will free it up. If there is a `foo=pow1;` in between, then the object has two refenreces, the object will not be collected if the first reference is gone. And `foo = someArray;` makes a reference to the object. You are now familiar with concepts that practizing junior Java devs have troubles with! :)